# How could connect() fail and set errno to EADDRINUSE

Tags: c, sockets, posix

I'm writing some critical code and need at one point to establish a TCP connection using `connect()`.

I dig into POSIX manpages to ensure that my code is fully POSIX compliant, and have to write unit tests covering all possible error cases.

Considering this [document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/connect.html), I fail to understand what the following means:

> EADDRINUSE
>   Attempt to establish a connection that uses addresses that are already in use.

At first sight I thought I could be triggered by the lack of ephemeral port, but this error is reported by `EADDRNOTAVAIL` (which I successfully triggered in an unit test).

Concretely, what does it mean? Which condition could lead to this error? I understand the semantic for this error on `bind()`, but how could `connect()` raise that?

Comment: What happens if you use up all ports in the ephemeral range, then close some of the sockets and immediately try to connect? I believe you can get EADDRINUSE in this case.

Comment: I don't think you're correct about `EADDRNOTAVAIL`. It means 'the specified address is not available from the local machine.' That would be caused during `bind()`, by specifiying a non-local IP address.

Comment: On Linux, the `connect()` man page states that:

 `EADDRNOTAVAIL` (Internet  domain  sockets)  The socket referred to by sockfd had not previously been bound to an address and, upon attempting to bind it to an ephemeral port, it was determined that all port numbers in the ephemeral port range are currently in use.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for the suggestion, just tested this, on Linux, I also get the `EADDRNOTAVAIL` in this scenario, not `EADDRINUSE`. The kernel is smart enough to notice that ports in `TIME_WAIT` state are not available.

Comment: I've only seen reports of such status from FreeBSD, so perhaps it doesn't happen on Linux.

Comment: This also may happen with intterrupted and restarted syscalls. Or not. The specs are rather vague. Se e.g. http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/connect-intr.html

Answer (score 1):

My feeling, though this is guesswork, is that this error is for non-TCP sockets, specifically unix sockets - `AF_UNIX (also known as AF_LOCAL)`

The linux [connect() mangpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) puts it just slightly differently than the one you linked:

> EADDRINUSE
>                 Local address is already in use.

The usage of the word "Local" led me to the `unix` [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) which states

> EADDRINUSE
>                 The specified local address is already in use or the
>                 filesystem socket object already exists.

Comment: Not connected UNIX socket (`SOCK_DGRAM` type) need an explicit `bind()` so that the server can respond. However, in this case, I'd have the `EADDRINUSE` error at the `bind()`, not at the `connect()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the link which you have given, it says:

*If the socket has not already been bound to a local address, connect() shall bind it to an address which, unless the socket's address family is AF_UNIX, is an unused local address.*

This could be triggering the error mentioned by you.

Comment: As I read and tested it, the lack of available unused local address is reported by `EADDRNOTAVAIL`.

Comment: Hmm.. Not sure..  Check if the link http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2006-December/024315.html helps.

Comment: Your remark lead me to a strange corner case: https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-net/2016-May/045331.html

I'll try to simulate this case, thanks.

Comment: But, it says "sometimes works wronly ". So, it should be just a bug. But, even with that, this error is returned for a busy local port with which it is not able to bind. Do let us know how your simulation went and if you were able to reproduce it. Thanks.